# React Native Appium couldn't find Automation id for view of style position: absolute in iOS

Tags: react-native, appium, ui-automation

**iOS::** Cant't find automation id for floating button `position: 'absolute'` in app when floating button is in top of `FlatList`. When I removed the flatList, I can able to find the automation id in **Appium** tool.

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={AppStyles.secondaryContainer}>
                <NavigationEvents
                    onDidFocus={() => this.onScreenFocused()}
                    onDidBlur={() => {
                        clearInterval(this.backgroundTimer);
                    }}
                />
                {this.renderStaffSelection()}
                {this.renderStaffList()}
                {this.renderAddButton()}
                {this.state.showAddEmployeeModal && this.renderAddEditEmployeeModal(EMPLOYEE_TYPE.ADD)}
                {this.state.showEditEmployeeModal && this.renderAddEditEmployeeModal(EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EDIT)}
                {this.state.showDeleteModal && this.renderDeleteStaffModal()}
            </View>
        );
    }

renderAddButton() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.addItemAbsoluteViewStyle} accessible={false}>
                <T2STouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={1}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({ showAddEmployeeModal: true });
                    }}
                    screenName={SCREEN_NAME.STAFF_LIST}
                    id={VIEW_ID.ADD_STAFF_BUTTON}
                    accessible={true}
                >
                    <T2SCustomIcon name={ICO_MOON.ADD} size={30} style={styles.plusIconStyle} />
                </T2STouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

addItemAbsoluteViewStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 20,
        bottom: 40,
        backgroundColor: Palette.carrotOrange,
        borderRadius: 28,
        height: 56,
        width: 56,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        shadowColor: Palette.darkBlack,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        elevation: 10
    }
```